# Firebase FCM returns Unauthorized error with right server key

Tags: firebase, curl, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a push notification from my server using Firebase Cloud Messaging but keep getting the following error:

> Client error: `POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/messages:send` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response... Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access

I have looked everywhere online and everywhere made mention of "using the Server Key instead of the API Key". I am doing this and still receiving the error. Nothing online has helped.

Here is my request:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/messages:send

Headers:
    Authorization: Bearer <MY SERVER KEY>
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded (I have also tried application/json)

Body:
    {
        "message": {
            "topic": "",
            "notifications": {
                "title": "Some title",
                "body": "Some notification body"
            }
        }
    }
```

Push notifications directly from the Firebase console work just fine, I just can't get this to work server side.

Comment: Sounds like whatever you're passing for the server key is invalid.

Comment: @DougStevenson - I copied the server key from the Firebase dashboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are using the [v1 HTTP API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages), but you're trying to authorize it using the instructions from the [legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).  They aren't compatible.  As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize-legacy-protocol-send-requests) states:

> Important: The server key found in the console cannot authorize send
>   requests made via the HTTP v1 API—it is used only for legacy HTTP and
>   XMPP requests.

If you want to use the v1 API, must follow the instructions in the [v1 API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize-http-v1-send-requests).  If you don't want to use the v1 API, then you will have to use the legacy API instead.